# Capture output arguments as separate from PHP exec()

Tags: php, c++, g++

I have a simple C++ program I want to execute with PHP through the function exec() and I want to capture the output variables as separate so I can perform further calculations in PHP. I am using g++ (GCC) 4.8.1 to compile the program.

The C++ code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string test = "This is a test string";
    int n1=3, n2=4, n3=5;
    cout<<test<<n1<<n2<<n3;
    return 0;
}
```

The PHP code:

```
<?php
    $dir = getcwd();
    $command = "g++ ".$dir."\\files\\index.cpp -o ".$dir."\\files\\output.out";
    exec($command, $asdf);
    exec($dir."\\files\\output.out", $test);

    print_r($test);
?>
```

The output I get is:

```
Array ( [0] => This is a test string345 )
```

The output I want is:

```
Array ( [0] => This is a test string [1] => 3 [2] => 4 [3] => 5 )
```

Which can be achieved by changing the folowing line in the C++ code:

```
cout<<test<<endl<<n1<<endl<<n2<<endl<<n3;
```

Is it possible to achieve the same result without adding the newline character between each variable? Can the variables be somehow captured as they are?

Comment: You could set them as environment vars (not sure how in c++) and then get in PHP with `$_ENV` or `getenv()`.

Comment: I think it is insane to compile and execute a C++ script (unless you are teaching c++ via PHP)

Comment: Agreed with @DieterLücking, why compile from PHP and why is the newline separator a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Somehow you need to separate outputs, if you don't want to use new line one way is to define an separator. You need To make sure that you are not using your separator anywhere else.

For example if separator is: "#!#!#"

Change following code in c++

```
cout<<test<<n1<<n2<<n3;
```

To:

```
String sep = "#!#!#";
cout<<test<<sep<<n1<<sep<<n2<<sep<<n3;
```

and to get outputs in php:

```
print_r( explode ("#!#!#", $test);
```

Comment: I considered this solution but it's rather ugly. Why use a variable as a separator when you can use a newline character?

Comment: @Martin My answer was based on this part of your question: "Is it possible to achieve the same result without adding the newline character between each variable?"